# Handle arrays in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, view, laravel

I am learning laravel and trying to create a community with laravel. I stuck at some part and need to ask you guys.

Right now I am trying to displaying posts to reader.

This is what i accomplish so far 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/lc5gX.jpg]

with this code :

```
public $restful = true;
public function get_index($title = '')
{
    //Do we have an arguement?
        if(empty($title))
        {return Redirect::to('dashboard');}

    $view = View::make('entry');
    $query = DB::table('threads')->where('title', '=', $title)->first();

    //Do we have this thread?
        if(!$query)
        {return Redirect::to('entry/suggest');}
    //We have? so lets rock it!
    $view->title = $query->title; //we get the title.

    $thread_id = $query->id;

    //getting posts.

    $posts = DB::table('posts')->where('thread_id', '=', $thread_id)->get();


    $view->posts = $posts;

  return $view;
}
```

and the view is :

```
<div id="entrybox">
    <h2>{{$title}}</h2>
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <p class="entry"><span class="entrynumber">1</span><span class="entry_text">{{$post->post_entry}}</span></p>
    <p align="right" class="edate"><span class="entry_user">{post_row.POST_USERNAME}</span> <span class="entry_date">{post_row.DATE}</span></p>
@endforeach
</div>
```

But the hard part(for me) is integrate posts with poster's username or other user info like e-mail for moderate privileges. However hey are in 'users' table.

Lets say $posts variable holds data of 10 posts for a thread
 *a post has thread_id , poster_userid, post, posted_date.

How can i grab username from 'users' table and send it to my view? I am sure i need to use foreach after selecting posts from database I just dont know how to handle arrays in foreach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look up how to set up models and their relationships using Eloquent ORM:
http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent

Specifically http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#relationships

You should have three models, Thread, Post and User (change poster_userid to user_id... or you can keep it but I wouldn't suggest it... just keep things simple. You could also use author_id or maybe even poster_id if that floats your boat.. just be sure to change 'user_id' out with what you choose)

```
//application/models/User.php

class User extends Eloquent {

 public function posts()
 {
      return $this->has_many('Post', 'user_id');
 }
}
```

and

```
//application/models/Post.php
class Post extends Eloquent {

 public function author()
 {
    return $this->belongs_to('User', 'user_id');
 }

 public function thread()
 {
    return $this->belongs_to('Thread', 'thread_id');
 }
}
```

and

```
 //application/models/Thread.php
    class Thread extends Eloquent {

     public function posts()
     {
          return $this->has_many('Post', 'thread_id');
     }

    }
```

and instead of

```
$query = DB::table('threads')->where('title', '=', $title)->first();

//Do we have this thread?
    if(!$query)
    {return Redirect::to('entry/suggest');}
//We have? so lets rock it!
$view->title = $query->title; //we get the title.

$thread_id = $query->id;

//getting posts.

$posts = DB::table('posts')->where('thread_id', '=', $thread_id)->get();
```

I would just put

```
$thread = Thread::where('title', '=', $title)->first();

if(!$query)
    {return Redirect::to('entry/suggest');}

$posts = $thread->posts()->get();
//or if you want to eager load the author of the posts:
//$posts = $thread->posts()->with('author')->get();
```

Then in your view you can look up the user's name by the following:

```
$post->author->username;
```

Easy peezy.

Comment: thats cool but, my posts table has 2 ID column one for AI and other for which thread they are related. should i have to change thread_id to id?

Comment: There should only be one primary key per table, and it's best to call it "id". Not sure how the rest of your program's logic ties into these models, however, if you want that primary key to be called something other than "id", then in the Post class you can set public $key = "thread_id"; for example.

Comment: thanks and also what i dont understand is find() function only gets 1 post of a thread but thread has 10 posts.

Comment: I rewrote the answer... hopefully this works out better for you.

Answer (score 1):

With Eloquent you can do this in multiple ways.

First, you can add a method to your post model that retrieves the related data. This approach will create a new query for each post, so it's normally not the best choice.

```
class Post extends Eloquent
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->has_one('User');
    }
}
```

Second, you can modify your initial query to join your desired data and avoid creating undo queries. Know as "[Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#eager)".

```
// Example from Laravel.com

foreach (Book::with('author')->get() as $book)
{
    echo $book->author->name;
}
```